# HTML PHP, how do i set the value of a radio button thats made with a while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, while-loop

I have radio buttons that are made from a while loop thats gotten from my database

basically i have an edit page for it but i cant seem to get the value from the database and set it in the radio button.

i want it so that the radio button thats been checked would appear

````
            <?php   $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT dishname FROM dishes WHERE category = 'Pasta'AND package = {$packageid}");
                    $stmt->execute();   
                    $stmt->bind_result($pasta);
        while($stmt->fetch()): ?>
              <input type ='radio' class = 'ds' id = 'pasta' value ='<?php echo $pasta ?>' name = 'pasta' required>
              <label for = 'pasta'><?php echo $pasta; ?></label>
            <?php endwhile; $stmt->close();?>```
````

Comment: First, that’s not how prepare works, you are performing string interpolation which is subject to SQL injection the same as concatenation. I’m unclear on your main problem.

Comment: Can you add the output of `$pasta`?